Website behaving differently when accessed from subdomain vs IP
I have a platform that was built using next.js with Postgresql which's hosted on AWS EC2, the platform works just fine when I access it from the IP, however, I added a subdomain and secured the platform using Cloudfront + AWS ACM.
Only then the website is working in a strange way, the following link shows two totally different images even though it's the same path! I am so confused:
http://12.34.56.78/_next/image?url=%2Farrow-down-circle.png&w=32&q=75 (The Correct one)
https://example.xyz.com/_next/image?url=%2Farrow-down-circle.png&w=32&q=75 (Another image)
What could I have done wrong? I am not sure where to dig

What are the CloudFront cache settings? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/QueryStringParameters.html

@MarkB I am using the Cache policy CachingOptimized and the Cache request policy Allviewer which I believe are the default ones from AWS.

Did you look at my link? You are using query parameters to specify what image to view. You need to make sure CloudFront is including the query parameters in the cache key. The behavior you describe is exactly what I would expect if you had CloudFront configured to ignore query parameters.

@MarkB Yeah, it was a caching issue from CloudFront, thanks for clarifying!

@MarkB The Op should try to revise/improve on this question or else it won't receive effective answer. Please
